# Prove $\lim_{n\to\infty} (x_n^{1/k})$ = $(\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n)^{1/k}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

Prove $$\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n^{1/k} = \left(\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n\right)^{1/k}.$$

$\lim x_n = x$, and $x_n \ge 0$,  $\varepsilon >0$

1. when $x=0$, $|x_n-x| \lt \varepsilon^k$ $\rightarrow$ $|x_n|< \varepsilon^k$ $\rightarrow$ $x_n^{\frac 1k} \lt \varepsilon$.
2. when $x \gt 0$, $|x_n^{\frac 1k}-x^{\frac 1k}|= \dfrac {|x_n-x|}{x_n^\frac{k-1}{k}+x^\frac{k-1}{k}}\le \dfrac {|x_n-x|}{x^\frac{k-1}{k}} $. Suppose $|x_n-x| \lt \varepsilon\cdot x^\frac{k-1}{k}$. Then, $|x_n^{\frac 1k}-x^{\frac 1k}|<\varepsilon$.

Could you tell me whether the proof is valid??

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sorry but the identity $$|a^{1/k}-b^{1/k}|=\frac{|a-b|}{a^{1-1/k}+b^{1-1/k}}$$ which you take for granted, is pure fantasy when $k\ne2$.

Comment: The inequality $(x+y)^{1/k} \le x^{1/k} + y^{1/k}$ for $k>1$, $x,y>0$ might be helpful.

Comment: [Don't use `\frac` in exponents or limits of integrals](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5057/290189).  I have changed the formatting of the title so as to
[make it take up less vertical space](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189) --
this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main
page is distributed evenly over the questions.
See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730)
for more information. Please take this into consideration for future
questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you mean $\lim_{x \to \infty}$, or do you really mean $\lim_{n \to \infty}$? And have you learned the general fact that if $f$ is a continuous function, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) = f(\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n)$? It may be algebraically neater to prove this general fact and then apply it to the case $f(x) = x^{1/k}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $x=0$ is fine as long as you make some mention of "there exists some $N$ so that for all $n\geq N$, $|x_n-x|<\epsilon^k$.

To deal with $x > 0$ case, let $y_n = x_n^{1/k}$, $x=y^{1/k}$, then

$$y_n^k - y^k = (y_n-y)(y_n^{k-1}+y_n^{k-2}y + \dotsb + y^{k-1})$$
Rearranging and rewriting in terms of $x_n$, and noting that all terms are non-negative

$$|x_n^{1/k}-x^{1/k}| = \frac{|x_n-x
|}{x_n^{1-1/k} + x_n^{1-2/k}x^{1/k} + \dotsb + x_n^{1/k}x^{1-2/k} + x^{1-1/k}}$$
Now, fix any $m$ that satisfies $0<m<x$. Given that $x_n\to x$, it follows that there must exist some $N_1$ so that $m < x_n$ for all $n\geq N_1$ (as $x_n$ eventually gets arbitrarily close to $x$).

Pick $\epsilon > 0$, as $x_n \to x$ there exists some $N_2$ so that for $n\geq N_2$,
$$|x_n-x| \leq \epsilon m^{1-1/k} k$$
hence if $n \geq \max\{N_1,N_2\}$ then

$$|x_n^{1/k}-x^{1/k}|
< \frac{|x_n-x|}{m^{1-1/k}+m^{1-2/k}m^{1/k}+\dotsb + m^{1-1/k}}
= \frac{|x_n-x|}{km^{1-1/k}}
< \epsilon
$$

Comment: Could you tell me how to do this "$y_n^k - y^k = (y_n-y)(y_n^{k-1} +y_n^{k-2}y+...+y^{k-1})$"??

Comment: In summation notation, changing to $a$ and $b$, expand and then remove the last and first term from the sums respectively, i.e.,
\begin{align}
(a-b)\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} a^i b^{k-1-i}
&= \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} a^{(i)+1} b^{k-1-i} - \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} a^i b^{(k-1-i)+1}\\
&=  \sum_{i=0}^{k-2} a^{i+1}b^{k-1-i} + a^{(k-1)+1} - \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} a^ib^{k-i}  - b^{k-(0)}\\
&= a^k - b^k + \underbrace{\sum_{i'=1}^{k-1} a^{i'}b^{k-i'} - \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} a^ib^{k-i}}_{=\;0}\\
&= a^k-b^k
\end{align}
where we substituted $i'=i+1$ in the first sum.
$$

Comment: Alternatively, use polynomial division to compute $$\frac{a^k-b^k}{a-b}$$ directly.

Comment: I got it. Thanks for detailed explanation !!

Comment: I am sorry. Do you mind if I ask you to show how to rearrange in terms of $x_n$ ? For example, just one $y_n^{k-2}y$ to $\frac 1{x_n^{1- \frac 1k}} x^{\frac 1k}$

Comment: My apologies, I wrote the substitution incorrectly. $y_n = x_n^{1/k}$ so the denominator is given by
$$\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} y_n^i y^{k-1-i} = \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} x_n^{i/k} x^{(k-1-i)/k} $$